# Как сделать вставку дива в динамически создаваемую html разметку?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, html5

Не работает вставка div в динамически создаваемый html код.

Не работает эта часть кода:

```
 $('.Digital, .iron75').append('<div class="clearfix"></div>');
```

Вот весь код:

```
$(function() {
   function renderWorked(arr) {
       var Category = {};
       arr = $.map(arr, function(item) {
           var div = $("<div/>", {
                   "class": "works" + item["Category"]
               }),
               img = $("<img/>", {
                   src: "/Kvinto/img/works/preview/" + item["image-data"],
                   attr: {
                       "data-video": item["data-video"],
                       "data-alt-src": item["data-alt-src"]
                   }

               }),
               h3 = $("<h3/>", {
                   html: item["title"]
               });
           Category[item["Category"]] ? (div = Category[item["Category"]]) : 
           (Category[item["Category"]] = div);  
           div.append($("<div/>", {
               html: [img, h3],
               "class": "work-wrapper"
           }));
           return div
       })
       $('#cases').append($("<div/>", {
           html: arr,
           "class": "works block"
       }))

   }
   var arr = [{
           'Wraper': '2',
           'Category': 'iron75',
           'data-video': 'r3-K4vdvRe6E',
           'data-alt-src': 'r3-K4dvvRe6E',
           'image-data': 'r3-K4vvdRe6E.jpg"',
           'title': 'iron75 <br> (пример2)'
       },{
           'Wraper': '1',
           'Category': 'Digital',
           'data-video': '5n_aW-dPRIQ0',
           'data-alt-src': '5n_aW-dPRIQ0',
           'image-data': '5n_aW-PdRIQ0.jpg"',
           'title': 'Digital <br> (пример1)'
       },{
           'Wraper': '1',
           'Category': 'Digital',
           'data-video': '5n_aW-dPRIQ0',
           'data-alt-src': '5n_aW-dPRIQ0',
           'image-data': '5n_aW-PdRIQ0.jpg"',
           'title': 'Digital <br> (пример1)'
       }, {
           'Wraper': '2',
           'Category': 'iron75',
           'data-video': 'r3-K4vdvRe6E',
           'data-alt-src': 'r3-K4dvvRe6E',
           'image-data': 'r3-K4vvdRe6E.jpg"',
           'title': 'iron75 <br> (пример2)'
       }

   ]

   renderWorked(arr);
```

Код вставки дива:

```
     $('.Digital, .iron75
      ').append('<div class="clearfix"></div>');
```

Comment: А откуда берутся элементы с классами `Azk`, `FastFood`, `Fitness`, `Cinema`, `Restaurant` и элементы с магическим тегом `Retail`?

Comment: Если в консоли ошибки? Если нет, то добавьте к вашему списку `body`. Как минимум в конце страницы должно появиться. Если появится, значит система не может найти элементы, которые вы перечисляете.

Comment: Простите допустил ошибку при публикации вопроса , уже исправил.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Valeriy1996/48u3mx4w/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял ваш код, то проблема в это месте:

```
var div = $("<div/>", {
    "class": "works" + item["Category"]
}),
```

Вы забыли пробел после слова `works` и получается, что вы создаете div c классами `worksDigital` и `worksiron75`. А ищите потом просто `Digital` и `iron75`.

Comment: Вы гений ! Спасибо , что заметили .Спасибо за подсказку!!!)))

Comment: Я не гений, я сам очень не внимательный и поэтому стараюсь такие вещи проверять раз по 100 =)